# Redirecting all www routes to respective non-www routes

Tags: nginx, redirect, routes

I have the current rule for my nginx routes:

```
        listen   80;
        server_name  www.domain1.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain1.com/$1 permanent;
```

This works but only for the root path and not other routes.  For example, a route like www.domain1.com/users/1 gets redirected to domain1.com.  How do ensure that www.domain1.com/users/1 gets routes to domain1.com/users/1?

I got this to work by adding a '$' at the end:

> rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://your_domain.com/$1  permanent;

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite you have there actually should work. That said, you don't need the capture at all as Nginx has already done that for you. You can just use

```
rewrite ^ http://domain1.com$request_uri? permanent;
```